# How to make parameter name suggestions work?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a `powershell` module to store some reusable utility functions. I created script module **PsUtils.psm1** and script module manifest **PsUtils.psd1**  (used these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/10-script-modules?view=powershell-7.2)). My problem is that when I import this module in another script `Visual Code` does not suggest parameters names. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When I hover cursor over the function I only get this:

[image]

**PsUtils.psm1**

```
function Get-Filelist {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $DirectoryPath
    )
    Write-Host "DIR PATH: $DirectoryPath"
}
```

**PsUtils.psd1 (excerpt)**

```
...
FunctionsToExport = '*'
```

I have `Powershell` extension installed. Do I need to install anything else to make the suggestions work? **What am I missing?**

Comment: Does it work in PowerShell ISE?

Comment: @Otter, yes it does. When I type `Get-Filelist -D` and press **tab** it expands to`Get-Filelist -DirectoryPath`

Comment: Is the language mode in VScode in the bottom right set to PowerShell?

Comment: @Otter, yes it is. I have a freshly installed `Visual Code` and I haven't had a chance to mess anything up yet.

Comment: what is `editor.suggest.showfunctions` set to in your VSCode settings? try setting it to `true`

Comment: @Otter, it's set to true in the editor settings . I've also added it to `settings.json` and nothing has changed.

Comment: @Otter, I added my module to a special powershell directory `C:\Users\mike-ladm\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and everything started working like expected in `Visual Code`.  Now I don't need to import this module since it's autoloaded. It's not a perfect solution, because I want this module to be local to my project. I wonder if "local" module suggestions are even supported.

Comment: They're supported, there is something else going on with your module. Try `$null = New-Module -Name tempModule -ScriptBlock { function Test-Func {param($Param1) $Param1 }}` then calling `Test-Func -` should complete `Param1`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, When I run your code in a terminal autocompletion works as expected. When I add your code to a `test.ps1`  the autosuggestion/autocompletion do not work. The editor sees that the `Test-Func` exists. No error or warning. And when I hover on the function invocation the editor shows only `function Test-Func`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Generally speaking, only [*auto-loading*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) modules - i.e., those in one of the directories listed in environment variable `$env:PSModulePath` - are *automatically* discovered.
- As of version v2022.7.2 of the PowerShell extension, the underlying PowerShell editor services make *no* attempt to infer from the current source-code file what modules in *nonstandard* directories are being imported *via source code in that file*, whether via [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) or `using module`

  - Doing so would be the prerequisite for discovering the commands exported by the modules being imported.
  - Doing so *robustly* sounds virtually impossible to do with the *static* analysis that the editor services are limited to performing, although it could work in simple cases; if I were to guess, such a feature request wouldn't be entertained, but [you can always ask](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues).

---

**Workarounds**:

Once you have imported a given module from a nonstandard location into the current session - either manually via the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) or by *running* your script (assuming the `Import-Module` call succeeds), the editor *will* provide IntelliSense for its exported commands from that point on, so your **options** are (use *one* of them):

- *Run your script in the debugger* at least once before you start editing. You can place a breakpoint right after the `Import-Module` call and abort the run afterwards - the only prerequisite is that the file must be syntactically valid.
- Run your `Import-Module` command manually in the PIC, replacing `$PSScriptRoot` with your script file's directory path.

  - Note: It is tempting to place the cursor on the `Import-Module` line in the script in order to use <kbd>F8</kbd> to run *just* this statement, but, as of v2022.7.2, this won't work in your case, because `$PSScriptRoot` is only valid in the context of running an *entire script*.
  - [GitHub issue #633](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/633) suggests adding special support for `$PSScriptRoot`; while the proposal has been green-lighted, no one has stepped up to implement it since.
- (Temporarily) modify the `$env:PSModulePath` variable to include the path of your script file's directory.

  - The most convenient way to do that is via the `$PROFILE` file that is specific to the PowerShell extension, which you can open for editing with `psedit $PROFILE` from the PIC.

    - Note: Make sure that profile loading is enabled in the PowerShell extension's settings.
  - E.g., if your directory path is `/path/to/my/module`, add the following:

    ```
    $env:PSModulePath+="$([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)/path/to/my/module"
    ```
  - The caveat is that *all* scripts / code that is run in the PIC will see this updated `$env:PSModulePath` value, so at least hypothetically other code could end up mistakenly importing *your* module instead of one expected to be in the standard locations.
  - Note that [GitHub issue #880](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/880) is an (old) proposal to allow specifying `$env:PSModulePath` entries as part of the PowerShell extension settings instead.

---

On a somewhat related note:

- Even when a module is auto-discovered / has been imported, IntelliSense only covers its *exported* commands, whereas while you're developing that module you'd also like to see its *private* commands. Overcoming this limitation is the subject of [GitHub issue #104](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/104).